# Mongoose - Singleton Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a CMS for a site. There is an about page that needs to have content from the CMS. There needs to be only one document acting as a config file for the about page. My proposed solution for this is:

1. Create an about page model.
2. On save I will check to see if there is an existing document.
3. If there is an existing document, update that document. If there isn't save a new one.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to do this in the `save` pre hook for my schema ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this could be done for a singleton model:

```
HomePageSchema.statics = {
 getSingleton: function (cb) {
       this.findOne()
           .sort({updated: -1})
           .limit(1)
           .exec(function (error, model) {
               if (error) {
                   cb(error, null);
               } else if (model == null) {
                   cb(error, new HomePage());
               } else {
                   cb(error, model);
               }
           });
   },
};
```

and then

```
HomePage.getSingleton((err, homepage) => {
 homepage.image = '/images/myImage.jpg';
   homepage.headline = 'Homepage Headline';
   homepage.save();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. However, there is a mistake, getSingleton takes 2 parameters, error and model, since that is what you send in the cb(). I was getting a null value otherwise. Please edit the code to say HomePage.getSingleton(function (err, homepage) {...

Comment: In addition, to get this code to work as an export, you must have the following sequence: HomePageSchema.statics = {....   , Then var HomePage = mongoose.model('Config', HomePageSchema);, Then module.exports = HomePage.

Comment: I'd just like to express my thanks and say that this solution (with @Totomobile 's addition) worked an absolute treat for me. I wouldn't have figured this out without this post.

Answer (score 1):

Try `findAndModify` of mongodb as long as you have same _id document will be updated else a new document will be created.

Same is incorporated in mongoose under [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in three ways:

1. Firstly call `findOne` then in callback you are checking if row exists and then if not exists(document === null) call `save`,
2. Use `findOneAndUpdate` method from Mongoose with option `upsert` to true,
3. Do it in as you described, by using prehook.

In that case I will prefer to use the first or second option. Hooks have some magic itself, which it means that for the person which is looking on the code for the first time, it will be a little bit harder to find what's going on :P But hook could be better solution if the same scenario(that document save action) is ran in many places. It's debatable issue - I've just put my two cents ...